# Updating the page number with OpenXML inside the page content (not in header)

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I have a Word document with the page number inside of the header. I update this document through OpenXML by adding new content. After that, when I open this document the page number is correctly (automatically) updated.

But now, I need to have this page number not inside the header but inside the page content. In this case the page number is not correctly (automatically) updated.

How to have this page number automatically updated ? Any ideas ?

PS: I already try this code without luck:

```
        DocumentSettingsPart settingsPart = mainPart.GetPartsOfType<DocumentSettingsPart>().First();
        //Create object to update fields on open
        UpdateFieldsOnOpen updateFields = new UpdateFieldsOnOpen();
        updateFields.Val = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue(true);
        // Insert object into settings part.
        settingsPart.Settings.PrependChild<UpdateFieldsOnOpen>(updateFields);
        settingsPart.Settings.Save();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've used the same field codes in the header as in the main content?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because I did a copy/paste of the fields.